# XML to express array of possible values?

Tags: xml

I have a list of variables, and these variables can have any amount of possible values.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Keys>
              <attr1>
                     <option>X</option>
                     <option>Y</option>
                     <option>Z</option>
              </attr1>
              <attr2>
                     <option>A</option>
                     <option>B</option>
                     <option>C</option>
              </attr2>
        </Keys>
```

Is what I wrote above correct, or is there a better way to express it?

Comment: This question is simply not very well expressed.  Just wanted to add a comment that the question should be more specific about what it thinks the problem with the current solution is and what the goals are (maybe give some context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to state that attr1 and attr2 tags are of the same type:

```
    <Keys>
          <Key name="attr1">
                 <option>X</option>
                 <option>Y</option>
                 <option>Z</option>
          </Key>
          <Key name="attr2">
                 <option>A</option>
                 <option>B</option>
                 <option>C</option>
          </Key>
    </Keys>
```

Also, you could add option order or priority, but not necessarily.
You also said "these variables can have any amount of possible values", what does "ANY" mean ?

If some variables can have infinite values (like entering a string in a text box), and you might want to add some resrtiction I can suggest something like

```
<Keys>
      <Key name="attr1">
             <Restriction attrType="string" maxLength="3" />
             <option>X</option>
             <option>Y</option>
             <option>Z</option>
      </Key>
      <Key name="attr2">
             <Restriction attrType="string" maxLength="1"/>
             <option>A</option>
             <option>B</option>
             <option>C</option>
      </Key>
      <Key name="attr3">
             <Restriction attrType="integer" maxValue="10" minValue="0"/>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>3</option>
             <option>4</option>
             <option>7</option>
             <option>9</option>                      
      </Key>
</Keys>
```

The rest depends on what you want to do with the code, I guess

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much. I am fairly new to XML.